# building with gtest gtest_force_shared_crt doesn't work

Tags: c++11, cmake, googletest

I have a project set to link with gtest like so:

```
FetchContent_Declare(googletest
                     GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest
                     GIT_TAG master
        )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

target_link_libraries(testlib PRIVATE projlib gtest_main)
```

as you can see I link to gtest and also make sure to set:

```
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
```

yet when I build my `projblib` with cmake I get that the run time library version still mismatch:

```
gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't matc
h value 'MDd_DynamicDebug'
```

Not sure why this happens and how to fix this, suggestions?

Comment: The option `gtest_force_shared_crt` affects on building googletest itself, so you need to set it before `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks it worked. I didn't know I have to include it before to take effect since building it with visual studio with cmake worked (before adding this line I still got the error, but after adding it even after the MakeAvailable part it worked)

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, very useful!

Comment: @Tsyvarev Your comment actually solved an issue I was having with linking against a static build of Google Test from source on Windows. I was very frustrated with `gtest_force_shared_crt` not working in my `CMakeLists.txt` in my project, but after I passed `-Dgtest_force_shared_crt=1` to the CMake configure command before calling the `cmake --build` command, everything worked. Thanks so much! Maybe Google needs to clarify when `gtest_force_shared_crt` is to be set.